# Pass a parameter to FileReader onload event

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I need to read some csv files, given by the user. Files are passed to the page/script using a drag and drop div, that handles the file drop as follows:

```
function handleFileDrop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    ...
}
```

I need to parse each file with a csv library that converts it into an array, but I also need to keep track of the file name I'm currently parsing. Here's the code I use to parse each file:

```
for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
    var currFile = files[x];
    var fileName = currFile.name;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile){
        return function(e){
            var csvArr = CSV.csvToArray( e.target.result, ";", true );
            console.log(csvArr); 
        };
    })(currFile);   
    reader.readAsText(currFile);
}
```

Until this, everything works great. What I need is to also pass the filename to the `reader.onload` event, eg:

```
reader.onload = (function(theFile){
    return function(e){

       ***** I need to have fileName value HERE *****

    };
})(currFile);
```

Is possible? How can I do this? Thanks in advance for any help, best regards

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(theFile){
    var fileName = theFile.name;
    return function(e){
        console.log(fileName);
        console.log(e.target.result);
    };
})(currFile);   
reader.readAsText(currFile);
```

Here, you're creating a new `fileName` variable each time a file is passed to the outer method. You're then creating a function which has access that variable (due to the closure) and returning it.

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much, I was pulling my hair out trying to do this. I think I'm starting to understand closures now!

Comment: How is it possible to get both the filename and the reader.result value ?

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code, where is 'theFile' coming from ? I can see where currFile is defined but what does 'theFile' relate to ?

Comment: @NiallJG If you look at what is assigned to the `onload` property, we're actually executing a function and passing in `currFile`. Inside that function, `theFile` is just a different name for the file that we've passed in. This allows us to store a reference to that file's name, which can be accessed once the file contents are actually read.

Comment: @sandoval31 Using the `e.target.result` property - I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is this considered closure? I don't t think that I have seen such syntax before (with `currFile` as argument in the end) and I just recently read about closures and this seems similiar.

Comment: @John The inner function is a closure, as it retains a reference to the `fileName` variable after it is returned. The syntax you're looking at is often refered to as an [Immediately-invoked Function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or IIFE for short.

Comment: Hey @Graham, first, this is a beautiful answer. If you have a list of files, does that mean you need to reassign onLoad for every file since we are passing the currFile to the closure? Thank you!

Comment: @Antuan If you have an array of files, and are reading them sequentially, then it might be better to take a different approach and create a counter variable that refers to the current array index. Then you'd just have one `onload` that would be able to access the original array of files and therefore the names. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdXJRY?editors=1011 as a basic example. If the files are large, then you may insetad consider a FileReader for each file and read them inside Workers to avoid locking the browser.

Comment: @Graham thank you so much for taking the time to reply and for making an example for me. I ended up having an onLoad for each file ~10 files, but I'll switch to this approach. It's more elegant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

## Use Blob API

Using the [new File / Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) it can be done much easier.

Your second code block - also solving your problem - could be rewritten as:

```
for (let file of files){
 (new Blob([file])).text().then(x=>console.log(file.name,x));
}
```

The Blob API uses Promises instead of Events like the Filereader API, so much less troubles with closures. Also the [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) *(x=>)* and [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) *for of,* make the code much more concise.

Check [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_blob).

## Use Fetch API

Also using the [Fetch API Response Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) it can be done more easy.

```
for (let file of files){
 (new Response(file)).text().then(x=>console.log(file.name,x));
}
```

Note of the missing `Array []` in the constructor.

Also [check support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_response_response).