# Pass size and name to the .onload event of JavaScript's FileHandler

Tags: javascript, filehandler

How is it possible to pass the name and size of a file to the .onload event of JavaScript's FileHandler. As you can see I'm using the (still undeclared) variables `size` and `name` in my Ajax call below. However, I somehow have to pass them from the `getData()` function.

I've found [Pass a parameter to FileReader onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937223/pass-a-parameter-to-filereader-onload-event) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
getData('file2093', 
  function(e) { 
    new Ajax.Request('/documents/2093', { 
      asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'patch', parameters:'document_payload=' + btoa(e.target.result) + '&amp;document_filename=' + btoa(name) + '&amp;document_size=' + btoa(size) 
      }); 
  })

function getData(inputField, onLoadCallback){
    var input = document.getElementById(inputField);
    var file = input.files[0];
    var size = file.size;
    var name = file.name;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = onLoadCallback
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), arguments after the first one get passed to the called function, along with any other arguments passed during the function invocation.

```
getData('',function(size,name,e){
...
});
...
fr.onload = onLoadCallback.bind(fr,size,name);
```

Otherwise set the onload to an anonymous function that calls the callback

```
fr.onload = function(e){
  onLoadCallback(size,name,e);
};
```

pass the filereader object as well in the second snippet if you need access to the reader object, the first snippet sets the context of the callback function so you can access the reader object by `this` in the callback