# How to pass event data and id to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using javascript to be able to display an image pre file upload but Im having this error...

I have a javascript function

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#image_preview_new').css("display", "block");
    var previewDiv = $('#previewing_new');
    previewDiv.attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

and I am calling the function via another script, but I need to be able to pass both the event data as well as an id into that function but it doesn't seem to work...

This is what I am currently using and it works...

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

This is what I've been trying and it doesn't work. If try and pass the id and the event data (e, id) it tells me that "e is not defined"...

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded(e, id);
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

function imageIsLoaded(e, id) {
    $('#image_preview_new').css("display", "block");
    var previewDiv = $('#previewing_new');
    previewDiv.attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

How can I get the event data as well as an id into this function.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `id`? you didn't use it in the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937223/pass-a-parameter-to-filereader-onload-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.change()` event,  `Function.prototype.bind()`

```js
function imageIsLoaded(id, e) {
  // `id` : `"abc"` , `e` : `event`
  console.log(id, e);
  // do stuff with `id`
  var previewDiv = $("#" + id);
  previewDiv.attr("src", e.target.result);
}

$(":file").change(function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // set `this` to `reader` at first parameter to `.bind()`
  // pass `id` : `"abc"` at second parameter `.bind()` , 
  // called at `imageIsLoaded`
  reader.onload = imageIsLoaded.bind(reader, "abc");
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file">
<br />
<img id="abc" />
```